# Different Results for distance by sqrt and veclen

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I'm trying a simple task of drawing a tangent to a circle. While I already succeded with the tangent cs option, I also want to use the library `calc` for the exact intersection points. I simply start from the middle of the circle and calculate the respective angle to the intersection point by acos of the adjacent leg and the hypotenuse. The first one is the radius, the second one I want to have calculated by the `calc` library. This is what I tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (13,9);
\coordinate (T) at (10,2);
%
\draw (T) circle (2);
\draw let \p1 = ($(A)-(T)$) in (T) --++ ({acos(divide(2,veclen(\x1,\y1)))}:2)--(A);
\draw (T) --++ ({acos(2/sqrt(3^2+7^2))}:2)--(A);
\draw (T) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, neither of the two intersection points are correct. Why is that?

Comment: You main problem is `divide(2,veclen ....)` because you divide  `2 cm` by a dimension with `pt`. Possible also `acos(divide(2cm,veclen(\x1,\y1)))}:2)`

Answer (score 3):

Like Alex wrote you need to add `atan(7/3)` but if you want to use `veclen` you also need to modify your expression to calculate the angle

Remark : compare the next codes (\x1 =85.35823pt \y1=199.1692pt)

```
\pgfmathparse{veclen(85.35823pt,199.1692pt)} \pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{veclen(3,7)} \pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{veclen(3cm,7cm)} \pgfmathresult
```

The pgfmanual gives only

> `veclen(x,y) \pgfmathveclen{x}{y}` Calculates sqrt(x^2 + y^2). This
>   uses a polynomial approximation, based on ideas of Rouben Rostamian
>
> 12.99976 result of `\pgfmathparse{veclen(12,5)} \pgfmathresult`

This is not enough. The dimensions are in pt. You have the possibility to give another unit
 for  example `\pgfmathparse{veclen(12cm,5cm)} \pgfmathresult`
 and the result is  369.87305 but in pt. Possible also `\pgfmathparse{veclen(12cm,5pt)}` but it's a bad idea to mix units.

The complete code with veclen

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (13,9);
\coordinate (T) at (10,2);
%
\draw (T) circle (2);
\draw[red]  let \p1 = ($(A) - (T)$), \n1={veclen(\x1/28.45274,\y1/28.45274)} in 
          (T) -- ++({atan(\y1/\x1) - acos(divide(2,\n1))}:2) -- (A);

 % or  acos(divide(2cm,veclen(\x1,\y1)))}:2   
 %  instead of     acos(divide(2,veclen(\x1/28.45274,\y1/28.45274)))}:2  

\draw[red]  let \p1 = ($(A) - (T)$), \n1={veclen(\x1/28.45274,\y1/28.45274)} in 
          (T) -- ++({atan(\y1/\x1) + acos(divide(2,\n1))}:2) -- (A);

\draw (T) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The simplest way with `veclen`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (13,9);
    \coordinate (T) at (10,2);
    \draw (T) circle (2);
    \draw let \p1 = ($(A)-(T)$), \n1={acos(divide(2cm,veclen(\x1,\y1)))}
     in (T) -- ++ ({atan(\y1/\x1) - \n1}:2)--(A)
        (T) -- ++ ({atan(\y1/\x1) + \n1}:2)--(A);
    \draw (T) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator doesn't add your angle to the angle of the `(T)--(A)` direction. Maybe try something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (13,9);
\coordinate (T) at (10,2);
%
\draw (T) circle (2);
\draw (T) -- ++({atan(7/3) - acos(2/sqrt(3^2+7^2))}:2) -- (A);
\draw (T) -- ++({atan(7/3) + acos(2/sqrt(3^2+7^2))}:2) -- (A);
\draw (T) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]